# How to get all running process and their command arguments in VB

Tags: vb.net

How can I a get all the running process and the command argument in VB?
I only found  all the process but can not found their command line arguments.

```
For Each OneProcess As Process In Process.GetProcesses
            ListBox1.Items.Add(OneProcess.ProcessName) '&""Environment.CommandLine)
```

How to get list of command lines?

Comment: what do you mean by command line argument?

Comment: If there is .exe file created by me and its running .  in that .exe file  i gave a port no (@@@@@)  a path(E:\qwrty)  . in the command propmt .....                                                                                                                 I have to get the command argument which is given through the command prompt

Comment: You want to get the port number that an application is connecting from as well as its filename path?

Comment: yes  , I have to get the port and  path which i have i given in command prompt...            i have 3 to 4 .exe file  (qw1.exe ,  qw2.exe, qw3.exe )  i have get  that.....                                                                                                           1st i use a listbox to get all running process and 2nd listbox to get qw.exe process . then  what to do???

Comment: Hold on it's a long way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's unstable (Unstable is the regex) approach:

This code will get you a 0-based array called `outputarray` which is the return of `netstat -aon` from `cmd.exe`. The array has three columns:

1. First column is the local address
2. Second Column is the distant address
3. Third column is the pid (Process ID)

### Part 1:

---

```
 Sub Main()
            'We will need to use netstat to get two things:
            'The connection address
            'and your processes PID
            Dim CMD As New Process
            CMD.StartInfo.FileName = "CMD.exe"
            CMD.StartInfo.Arguments = "/c netstat -aon"
            CMD.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
            CMD.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
            CMD.Start()
            'OutPut is our bucket that gets the spews of netstat
            Dim OutPut As String = CMD.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd
            'We will parse through Output using regex to get the address and the process pid
            Dim Pattern As String = "([\d\.:]+).+?([\d\.:]+).+\s(\d+)\s"
            Dim regex As New System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(Pattern,System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.Multiline)
            'We will put the result a string array of three columns
            Dim rowcount As Long = regex.Matches(OutPut).Count
            ' output is 0-based
            Dim outputarray(0 To rowcount - 1, 0 To 2) As String
            Dim i As Long = 0
            For Each match In regex.Matches(OutPut)
                For j = 0 To 2
                    outputarray(i, j) = match.groups(j + 1).ToString
                Next
                i += 1
            Next
            'Read Part 2
        End Sub
```

### Part 2:

Just run through all of your process and compare their ID to the last column of the array, if there is a match, bingo, you have the distant and remote address at your hand from the other two columns (The regex will work perfectly on a TCP IVP4 connection).

Comment: it shows  "RegularExpressions" is not a member of string

Comment: can you try it now if an error shows up tell me which line?

Comment: i want to know the command line arguments which are given by me to another process or some selective process......                                                                                                    it is showing some local add... and foreign add... state  port (tcp and udp)

Answer (score 1):

You can use WMI to get the command line for running processes. Something like this:

```
    Dim searcher As New ManagementObjectSearcher("root\CIMV2", "SELECT * FROM Win32_Process")

    For Each p As ManagementObject In searcher.[Get]()
        Dim commandLine As String = p("CommandLine")
    Next
```

The variable `commandLine` will give you the command line used to start the process (if applicable) or nothing if the process wasn't started from the command line. You can check the `Name` property (so `p("Name")`) to just get the processes that you are interested in (ie. qw1.exe, qw2.exe etc).

You will need to add this to the top of your code:

`Imports System.Management`

and add a reference to System.Management.

Comment: I'm writing something for you but it is kinda long.

Comment: What is the error? You probably need admin rights to access other processes.

Comment: Ok have updated the answer. You need to import System.Management and add a reference to it. Hopefully, this will sort your errors. Otherwise, @JLILIAman will have an alternative soon by the look of it.

Comment: And did you add the reference?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by 'the detail code' but if you mean how to add the reference: To add a reference, go to the Project menu and select 'Add reference'. Then choose Assemblies - Framework (this should be the default page anyway) and go down the list to find System.Management and check the box next to it. Apologies, if I have mis-understood.

Comment: how i put it into a  listbox

Comment: Are the names of the .exes already in a list box and you want to filter the complete process list down the processes in the list box or do you want to add all processes to a list box? Or something different?

Comment: i got all the .exe to list box......Then i have to find some .exe  from that  listbox......     without    If Item.StartsWith("*********") Then         Is there any other process

Answer (score 0):

i think this would be the simplest one

```
Imports System.Management
...

Dim searcher As New ManagementObjectSearcher( _
  "SELECT * FROM Win32_Process WHERE Name='Notepad.exe'")

 For Each process As ManagementObject in searcher.Get()
 Console.WriteLine(process("CommandLine"))
 Next
```